# Azure SQL - Login failed for user

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using a free azure subscription, have set up an SQL server (v12) and created a database onto it.

However i cant seem to log in using the server admin credentials that i set when prompted during the SQL server credentials.

Management Studio returns:

```
Cannot connect to <server name>...Login failed for user 'mickey'

SQLCMD -S <servername>.database.windows.net -U mickey@servername -P pass -q "select 1"
```

Returns

***Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login failed for user '***

Is there something i am missing? Been at this for hours

Comment: password seems to be wrong as per error message and it is 100% percent correct for these error messages

Comment: Have reset this countless times and re attempted to login but still get the same error

Comment: Turns out to be a password issue, cant figure out, but i reset the password on an entirely different machine, then run the connection test again on my machine, and this worked.

Comment: It could be the password contains a few special characters that sqlcmd does not handle (such as dollar, single or double quote, parentheses). I tried using the Azure interface and surrounding the password with single-quotes (we had a dollar-sign in the password), but that did not work. So, we simply removed the special character and now it is OK. see: Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd Login Failed and https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/08/09/vsts-azure-sql-database-deployment-task-keeps-failing-with-error-login-failed-for-user/

Answer (score 2):

It could be the password contains a few special characters that sqlcmd does not handle (such as dollar, single or double quote, parentheses). I tried using the Azure interface and surrounding the password with single-quotes (we had a dollar-sign in the password), but that did not work. So, we simply removed the special character and now it is OK. see: Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd Login Failed and https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/08/09/vsts-azure-sql-database-deployment-task-keeps-failing-with-error-login-failed-for-user/

Comment: I got the same error & searched a lot about it...
Your Solution worked for me as my password also contained a Dollar Sign...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server Management Studio, could you please check if you have SQL Server Authentication or Windows Authentication in the 'Connect to Server' dialog box? The connection to Azure SQL DB works with 'SQL Server Authentication' only.

Also on SQLCMD, please try the command without spaces between the parameter indicators and values. For example:

```
SQLCMD -Sin4live.database.windows.net -Umickey@servername -Ppass
```

rather than

```
SQLCMD -S in4live.database.windows.net -U mickey@servername -P pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It was actually a password issue, reset it from a different laptop and it worked.Could be a keyboard issue. Have had this with my godaddy  password reset too

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic, but I just faced this issue - I had exactly the same error message "Login failed for user" and I was 100% sure the password is correct. Despite that I did reset it few times - still couldn't manage to connect to it.

Turns out the problem was with the connection string, I tried to connect with IP address instead of FQDN.

Hope it helps somebody that came here with the same problem.