# Login failed for user 'san' in SQL Server on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database

I keep getting an error

> Login failed for user 'san'

while using Azure database from Web API with Entity Framework.

Here is the screen shot of SSMS. I am able to access the database from SSMS, but not from the Web API database call.

[image: image of ssms]

I tried to create a new login and user but getting an error

> User already exists

The same problem has been ask in the below link but those solution did not work for me

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141239/login-failed-for-user-on-sql-azure-from-azure-hosted-web-application

[Azure SQL - Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035464/azure-sql-login-failed-for-user)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102605/azure-sql-database-login-failed-for-user-in-application-but-works-fine-in-ssm

Here is the connection string

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:fetessbird.datatable.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Falcon;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=san;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

I am able to access the database from SSMS not from the webapi

Comment: san does not have rights to the database ....

Comment: How can I add rights can you Please let me know

Comment: You may not be able to .... but the easiest way is to double click the user in the server security, click mappings and give yourself some access - but if you dont have perms to do that it wouldnt be too surprising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the Falcon database using SQL Server Management Studio and run the following statements.

```
CREATE USER San FROM LOGIN San;
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'San';
```

Comment: I am very glad San! Enjoy SQL Azure!

Answer (score 1):

You just create a `LogIn` named *San* on the server, what you need now is to create a user related to this `LogIn` in the `Flcon` database, you should give it permissions to the db.

Go to Falcon -> Users -> RightClick -> New user

then follow the wizard.

Update:

To create the user:

```
CREATE USER San FOR LOGIN San WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Falcon;  
GO
```

Then you can give it rights as(if you already have the user the just give it rights):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'San' 
GO
```

Comment: Its already their I am getting error while creating "The server principal 'san' already exists"

Comment: CREATE USER <user_name, sysname, user_name>
 FOR LOGIN <login_name, sysname, login_name>
 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = <default_schema, sysname, dbo>
GO

-- Add user to the database owner role
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'<user_name, sysname, user_name>'
GO . This is what I get when I right click

Comment: @SanJaisy I say create a database user, not a login, because you already have the login.

Comment: Yes I am creating a user. Falcon --> security --> users --> right click . On right click the above script open

Comment: When I execute this command - CREATE USER san FROM LOGIN san; Its give me a error as - The login already has an account under a different user name.

Answer (score 0):

As from your screenshot the **login** san is created and valid on the SQL Server but you haven't given any permissions to the database you are connecting to from the API. The **login** san it's not an **user** on the database you want to access.

Comment: How Can I do that can you please let me know